# The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an angular 12 application and I have a service call which is returning an Object. I need to iterate through the object and display the values in the HTML.
The problem is that **I need to use strict typescript types. So "any" is not allowed**. Here is my working code and this works fine if I declare files: any; But I need to use strict typescript types so "any" is not allowed.

SERVICE CALL:

```
public getUserUploadedFileName() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url);
}
```

TS FILE:

```
files: any;
this._myService
        .getUserUploadedFileName()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.files = data;
        });
```

HTML :

```
<div *ngFor="let file of files">
        {{ file }} </div>
```

Comment: if you know what the response like, you could create an interface for it `export interface File { filename: string }` then `files: File[]`

Comment: My response if a big Object 
"approvedData": {
            "loanProduct": "Personal",
            "loanAmountLabel": "Loan amount",
            "loanAmount": "10000",
             ...
             ...
            "userUploadedFiles": ["mystatement.jpg", "mystatement1.jpg"]
        }

Is there any other option other than having an Interface?

Comment: have you tried `file: unknown`?

Comment: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Answer (score 0):

You could get the values by:

```
this._myService
        .getUserUploadedFileName()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.files = Object.values(data);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Chip. But what will be the file type. Like I said, I can't use 
files: any[];

Comment: files: <any> // as what files is will depend on what the value types are in your object.

With the above code, you should be able to use files: any[] = [];

Answer (score 0):

After imports section declare an interface fit your data properties:

```
//imports .....

export interface IResponseData {
property1:string;
property2:number;
property3:string;

}
files: Array<IResponseData>;
    this._myService
            .getUserUploadedFileName()
            .subscribe((data:Array<IResponseData>) => {
                this.files = data;
            });
```

Comment: Does not work.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Object[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2696)

Comment: code changed...

Comment: Again <any> cannot be used

Comment: check new update